# CUDA mixing float and double causing kernel to not execute

Tags: types, casting, cuda, floating-point, double

Using CUDA C I have a statistics kernel that when I add a breakpoint in VS2012 anywhere within the kernel and include the stddev line with the preceding variable definitions:

```
double mean, stddev, sumOfValues, sumOfValuesSquared;
unsigned int n;

// acquire greater than 0 values for: sumOfValues, sumOfValuesSquared, and n

stddev = (float)(sqrt((double)(n) * sumOfValuesSquared - (sumOfValues*sumOfValues)) / (double)(n));
```

The breakpoint is never reached, and the kernel does not execute.  When I remove that single line, the kernel executes.  I thought it had to do with the sqrt, but it does not.  I have another line:

```
mean = sumOfValues / n;
```

When I use that line, it also does not execute the kernel.  What am I missing about type conversions in CUDA (is this a registers issue, or single precision vs. double precision)?

-- UPDATE (10/2/2013 14:25 CST) --

I adjusted the number of threads from 1, and then 1024.  The first run, it goes to my breakpoint, the second with the high thread count, the kernel does not execute.  Please see the code, below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int value;
} ValueStruct;

__global__ void FailsToExecute(ValueStruct *vs)
{
    unsigned int numerator = vs->value;
    unsigned int denominator= 3;
    bool eject = false;

    if(denominator > 0)
    {
         if(1.0f * numerator / denominator > 17.98f)
             eject = true;
         else
             eject = false;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ValueStruct *vsHost;
    ValueStruct *vsDevice;

    cudaMallocHost((void **)&vsHost, sizeof(ValueStruct));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&vsDevice, sizeof(ValueStruct));

    vsHost->value = 54;

    cudaMemcpy(vsDevice, vsHost, sizeof(ValueStruct), cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 blocks(5);
    dim3 threads(1024);

    FailsToExecute<<<blocks, threads>>>(vsDevice);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I calculate / cope with register boundaries, I don't know much about them?

Comment: Are you building the code for an architecture that supports `double`, i.e. compute capability 1.3 or higher?

Comment: Looks like you don't have enough registers.  Try to reduce the number of threads per block to see if it can run.

Comment: I guess this isn't your actual code. Try running your code with cuda-memcheck. You may have a data access violation in your for loop. Or else provide a complete reproducer code. SSCCE.org

Comment: I'm using compute capability 2.1, and yes the kernel is running a large number of threads. I couldn't reproduce in an example.  I'll adjust the threads in the example to see if it reproduces and post an update.

Comment: Posted update.  Upping the thread count reproduces the issue.

Comment: You could use the occupancy calculator spreadsheet to find out a thread block configuration that will fit the register usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernels that require more resources than are available (e.g. registers, shared memory) will not launch. This can be detected by appropriate error checking, for example as shown here:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/545591/how-to-debug-kernel-throwing-an-exception-/?offset=16

Due to allocation granularity effects that are different for each GPU architecture, the accurate calculation of resources required for the combination of a particular kernel with a particular launch configuration can be non-trivial. For this reason, I would suggest using the CUDA occupancy calculator which incorporates the granularity details. You can find the occupancy spreadsheet here:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls

Comment: In addition to lowering the thread count per block in order to comply with available occupancy, there was another major limiting factor when I was debugging my code.  Though the CUDA card I was using wasn't my primary, I had 2 monitors plugged into it.  After disconnecting the monitors, it had more resources available, thus more registers.  This may be a no-brainer to most, but being new to CUDA coding, one doesn't automatically think to disconnect monitors when debugging their code.  The cudaCheckLaunchError was key to tracking cudaGetLastError for kernel launches to zero-in.

Comment: Additionally, as instructed by the Occupancy Excel document, if you turn on verbose output during compiles, you can see the number of registers and other resources allocated via the compiler for each of your cuda kernels.  Dynamic memory allocations using multiple heaps/stacks can complicate tracking the resource allocations, but as long as you use cudaGetLastError after ALL kernel launches and cuda functions during debugging, debugging is an easy process. Finally, a word to the wise... don't use your GPGPU as a graphics card while expecting maximal resources to be available for compute fun.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the nvcc compiler optimized the kernel away to nothing?  Looking at the kernel function, I could see how this could safely be optimized to zero instructions, since it effectively doesn't do anything.

```
__global__ void FailsToExecute(ValueStruct *vs)
{
    unsigned int numerator = vs->value;
    unsigned int denominator= 3;
    bool eject = false;

    if(denominator > 0)
    {
         if(1.0f * numerator / denominator > 17.98f)
             eject = true;
         else
             eject = false;
    }
}
```

Setting `eject` doesn't matter since `eject` is never used again.  So we can scratch out those two assignments.  The expression in the if () condition doesn't modify anything, and since it there's nothing to do for either branch of the if statement, it looks like the if() can be removed.  And continuing likewise back up to the top of the kernel, it seems like it can all be optimized to nothing and still have the kernel produce the same result.

Maybe if you added some kind of output, like maybe an array of bools, and saved the results of `eject` into that array, then you would see the kernel being executed.

Comment: I thought about this same thing, and did test that.  If you diminish the thread count per block, threads(1) instead of threads(1024), code is generated, executed, and traceable--PTX is visible in the disassembler.  I've had coding difficulties because of the topic you pose, however.  It appears when you debug using NSIGHT, the 'registers', which are virtual registers, don't follow typical C scope concepts due to optimization.  Watched variables go out of scope quicker.  I'm sure it's necessary, I'm just getting used to it.  I don't believe that is what was affected the code in my case.